# How to code in django soft delete or how to filter query in model?

Tags: python, django, orm, soft-delete

how to filter query in the model?

```
class ABC(models.Model):
soft_delete = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ABC'
    <SOMETHING FUNCTION>
```

Can I write here some function like that it's possible

```
def get():
    queryset = ABC.objects.filter(soft_delete=0)
    retuen queryset
```

or any other solution?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#managers

Comment: More precisely, if you **never** want to see soft-deleted instances, [modify your manager's default queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) (and implement another special manager that does also show the soft-deleted objects to be used for admin purposes).

Comment: okay thanks, NavidZarepak, and dirkgroten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a custom manager is a good candidate for this task. The example would be:

```
from core.managers import ABCManager

class ABC(models.Model):
    soft_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # other fields
    objects = ABCManager()
    # active = ABCActiveManager()
```

store your managers in the separated file (managers.py):

```
from django.db.models import Manager

class ABCManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = super().get_queryset()

        query = query.filter(soft_delete=False)

        return query
```

But this is a global solution, `objects` will always return instances with `soft_delete=False`. In case (most likely) when you also need to get deleted objects you could instead of overriding default (objects) manager name your own differently.

---

Also, you could solve the issue with the class method:

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    soft_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @classmethod
    def active_records(cls):
        return cls.objects.filter(soft_delete=False)
```

And call it on the class level like so:

```
ABC.active_records()
# <QuerySet [<ABC: ABC object (1)>, <ABC: ABC object (2)>]>
```

It's quite hard to suggest a solution because it really depends on how you're going to use it later.

Answer (score 0):

A instance will be soft delete or visible. So `soft_delete` should be a boolean field.

```py
class ABC(models.Model):
    soft_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # other fields
```

Then you can get the soft deleted objets with this query:

```
queryset = ABC.objects.filter(soft_delete=True)
```

Other objects which are not soft deleted:

```
queryset = ABC.objects.filter(soft_delete=False)
```

All objects:

```
queryset = ABC.objects.all()
```

Comment: Yes but then every time you use the filter query when you don't need a soft delete object, so this thing not uses repeatedly behind this question.